# A word coined to stand for men who like to teach women to behave?

Tags: word-request

I once encountered a word on Twitter that means a man thinks that a woman doesn't know more than him about what she is doing. For instance, such a guy would command a lady how to drive in his way when the woman is in the driver's seat(literally) and the man in the passenger seat. And a male student would like to guide a female in coding even though he is not asked to.

What is that word?

Comment: He's a ***chauvinist*** ([***chauvinism**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chauvinist) - an attitude of superiority toward members of the opposite sex*.)  Sometimes made more explicit by calling him a ***male chauvinst pig** (MCP)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Don't write answers in the comments, please.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - write away, pal!

Comment: I can think of a word, but I might get in trouble if I write it here. It starts with an A.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing that word is [**mansplaining**](https://www.google.com/search?q=mansplaining&oq=mansplaining&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> the explanation of something by a man, typically to a woman, in a manner regarded as condescending or patronizing.

And here's a flowchart taken from the [BBC website](https://www.bbc.com/worklife/article/20180727-mansplaining-explained-in-one-chart)

> [image]

Comment: I believe that’s it.  I believe “henpecking” would be the word when the roles are reversed.